# How do I read from the dbo.AspNetUsers table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I want to retrieve data from the Identity-table `dbo.AspNetUsers`, but I haven't figured out how to query it.

This is my db-context:

```
public class ProjectsDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ProjectsDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectsDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasMany(c => c.ChildProjects)
            .WithOne(p => p.ParentProject)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentProjectId);
    }
}
```

This is my `User`-class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the query I have, which doesn't work:

```
List<User> projectOwners = await db.Users.ToListAsync();
```

The error message I get is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Projects.Models.User>'

If I replace `List<User>` with `var` in the query, the error goes away, but the collection I get does not contain any of the properties from my own `User`-class.

How do I access the `AspNetUsers`, including my own extra properties defined in `User`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumig you're setting your project up more or less according to standard boilerplate, I believe you can cast override type of your identity user like so:

#### Startup.cs

```cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // pretty standard initialisation so far
            services.AddDbContext<ProjectsDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false) // this is the key - put your custom User Identity here
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectsDbContext>();
        }
```

#### ProjectsDbContext.cs

```cs
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProjectsDbContext: IdentityDbContext<User> // this is your custom User type
    {
        public ProjectsDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectsDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

then, since you are changing the data model, you will need to migrate the schema:

```bsh
PM> Add-Migration change_IdentityUser
PM> Update-Database
```

you will notice the migration adds your custom fields to the table:

```cs
public partial class change_IdentityUser : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "FirstName",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "LastName",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                nullable: true);
        } 
.......
```

and finally, all references to `SignInManager`/`UserManager` and other helpers will need to be updated with new generic type parameter:

#### _LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager
```

Comment: That gives me runtime exception "Unable to cast object of type ..."

Comment: right. I think your DbContext should be `ProjectsDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>` - I'll update the answer

Comment: Won't that mean I will have to make changes to all the Identity views? They all reference `IdentityUser`.

Comment: I changed the context, and now I get "Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context." when I try to register a new user in the app.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems there was a bit more work to do - see updated answer and let me know if that helps at all

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to change all the type references in the views (such as _LoginPartial.cshtml), but I kind of understand why that's necessary. I don't have time to try it out today, but will look into it tomorrow.

Comment: This solution requires you to change from `IdentityUser` to `User` in quite a large number of places in the Identity razor pages and code behind. But it works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 5):

With EF Core with, the table AspNetUsers is mapped to the Users DbSet, so you can easily reference it by

```
db.Users
```

If you customise the AspNetTable, adding your own fields, such as FirstName, LastName, then you need the to derive from `IdentityUser` as per @timur's answers, but you should still be able reference the table with just `db.Users`

Comment: Be sure to update your data context file, my example would be  'public partial class APP_DataContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>     you will need to get the updated NuGet as well for EF Identity.